# Java split (?=pattern) not longest match

Tags: java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "8.adfafd9.abcdefg10.haadfagada11.fsfdfare";
    String[] results = str.split("(?=(\\d+[、.]))");
    for (int i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("a[" + i + "] = \"" + results[i] + '"');
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```java
a[0] = "8.adfafd "
a[1] = "9.abcdefg "
a[2] = "1"
a[3] = "0.haadfagada "
a[4] = "1"
a[5] = "1.fsfdfare"
```

This is what I want:

```java
a[0] = "8.adfafd "
a[1] = "9.abcdefg "
a[2] = "10.haadfagada "
a[3] = "11.fsfdfare"
```

How can I get the results I want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```java
String str = "8.adfafd 9.abcdefg 10.haadfagada 11.fsfdfare";
String[] a = str.split("\\s+(?=\\d+\\.)");
```

Comment: a[0] = "8.adfafd 9.abcdefg 10.haadfagada 11.fsfdfare"

Comment: Shouldn't the split pattern be `\\s+(?=\\d+\\.)` ?  Also, maybe just split on spaces here.

Comment: \\s+(?=\\d+\\.) this can work,thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex match all approach here, rather than splitting:

```java
String str = "8.adfafd 9.abcdefg 10.haadfagada 11.fsfdfare";
String pattern = "\\b\\d+\\.\\S+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(matches);
// [8.adfafd, 9.abcdefg, 10.haadfagada, 11.fsfdfare]
```

Comment: String str = "8.adfafd9.abcdefg10.haadfagada11.fsfdfare";
What to do when there are no spaces